# How to speed up python scripts by running simultaneously & sequentially

Tags: python, performance, gurobi

I have an optimization program (currently a jupyter notebook that outsources the optimization itself to gurobi cloud) that I need to run many iterations of. So far, I've tried running multiple versions of the same script simultaneously overnight. However, this taxes my computer (ie, it's crashed once or twice, and is very slow to respond in the morning) and seems to contribute to my program failing sometime around 7 hours after I start it, before it's completed. (The program does not throw an error message; it just seems to stop producing optimization outputs. This seems to happen less when I try to do fewer simultaneous runs.)

I suspect that part of my issue is with my memory getting full. I'm wondering if I might have more success if I run my scripts both parallel and in sequence, so the memory clears. I clearly am a novice about computer performance, though, so advice is helpful.

My current situation is this: At 8pm, I start running scripts A and B in parallel, each of which contains 100 separate optimizations (as part of a for loop). This seems to keep the outputs of all 100 optimizations in memory until morning, which seems to slow down my computer considerably and eat up a bunch of storage (which is free again after I restart my computer).

Instead, I'm wondering if it would improve my computer's performance to split A into A1 (with the first 50 optimizations) and A2 (with the second 50 optimizations), and B into B1 and B2, and then to run A1 and B1 in parallel with A2 and B2 set to run after A1 and B1 complete.

**Could anyone advise on whether this would be expected to improve my performance?**

Comment: Running in parallel is likely to use _more_ memory, not less.

Comment: Yes, I expect that--my question is whether I can reduce my overall memory usage by making my scripts shorter and running them sequentially (so, still employing parallel runs to get more done, since my memory can support that, but trying to *also* employ sequential runs to reduce memory usage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the file-splitting specifically but here are a couple of other things that could be good to try,

1. [Reduce the number of threads](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/threads.html#parameter:Threads)
2. Set the solve method=1, [this is something that gurobi suggests](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/method.html) here to do if memory is tight
3. Set the [nodefilestart parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/nodefilestart.html) to something small

These are all however things that reduce memory whilst your model is running. The other thing is reducing the number of models you have stored. This technically should happen automatically but I think I have seen it fail in the past. In which case you could try to explicitly delete your model like `del model` at the end of your loop before beginning the next.